# How reliable/portable are Nix built-ins/commands (echo, ps, sort, uniq) from Debian to other distros

Tags: debian, shell-script, posix, portability

I've coded a script and am wondering about it's reliability / portability.

```
#!/bin/bash
threadsPlease() {
  ps -mo lwp,c -p $1 | sort -gk 2 | uniq -f 1 
}

THREAD_LINE=$( threadsPlease $1 | grep -v - | tail -1)

THREAD10=$(echo $THREAD_LINE | awk '{print $1}')
THREAD16=$(printf '%x\n' $THREAD10)

JAVA_LINE=$(jstack $1 | grep $THREAD16)
echo "OS data (thread, CPU usage %): " $THREAD_LINE
echo "Java thread: " $JAVA_LINE
```

Script displays system and Java thread data, given Java PID. Sample execution:

```
./whichThreadIsIt.sh 6814
OS data (thread, CPU usage %):  6838 3
Java thread:  "AWT-EventQueue-0" #19 prio=6 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f50f4090800 nid=0x1ab6 waiting on condition [0x00007f510dfbb000]
```

Q1: Aside from the obvious ("jstack/java/awk/... is not available or not in path" or "input data given wrongly"), when this will not work the intended way (Ubuntu/Debian)?

Q2: "It's easier to port a shell, than a shell-script", my friend likes to say. So, how much more effort this would need to work in Fedora / CentOS, Free BSD and Solaris? Am I wrong expecting it to run without troubles (assuming Bash present on those boxes)?

Comment: take a look at some larger 3rd-party software installation scripts, if you can put your hands on them. Ones that support multiple target OS's like the ones you're interested in. See the gyrations they go through to find the programs they're looking for -- even basic ones like ""ps" and "sort" can have non-overlapping flags to do what you want to do. Some OS's will have them in different paths altogether.

Comment: Are you talking about [Nix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nix_package_manager) or about Unix? If you're talking about Unix, please write “Unix”.

Comment: @Gilles, thanks, in my circles when you speak of Unix&Linuxes you usually say Nixes.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

May or may not increase the portability, as if `bash` is actually installed on a *BSD system, it usually exists at `/usr/local/bin/bash`. However, `env` may not be portable, though that would only be for really old or weird unix systems.

`ps` is an especially not-portable command, especially if you intend to use BSD/GNUisms on a SysV system (e.g. Solaris). Installing the GNU tools somewhere and then fixing PATH to include those would be one solution.

Comment: GNU tools don't include `ps`. There's no alternative to the OS's native `ps` command — it parses some data structures or files that vary a lot between Unix variants.

Comment: So I take it that while on Debian and derivatives the location for bash would be as in the script, in BSD and Solaris it would fail (no `ps`, `bash`). Anything in the script itself that could cause failure on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/...? Anything not so large that I can do to make script portable to Solaris (preferred more than BSD)?